# Invalid maximum heap size?

Tags: java, grails, jvm

I am running an grails application for my project in IntelliJ and I have set the vm options to :

```
-Dserver.port=8080 -Xms3g -Xmx3g -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit -Xverify:none
```

The logs are :

> Running Grails application
>
> Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx4096M
>
> The specified size exceeds the maximum representable size.
>
> Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
>
> Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
>
> Error | Forked Grails VM exited with error

Please help me with that ?

Comment: How much RAM you have available? What operating system do you use? Which JDK have you installed?

Answer (score 7):

If your JVM is 32bit, then heap size should be lower than 4gb. Either you can install 64bit JVM, or set the maximum heapspace to 2GB with `-Xmx2048M`. I had similar problem and this worked for me, hope this helps you as well.

Comment: i have jdk installed amd-64 does it includes jvm ?

Comment: please run "java -version" in command line to see whether jvm 32 or 64. And yes jdk contains everything that is in the jre, because jdk is superset of jre

Comment: I have ubuntu installed it is not showing whether jdk is 32 bit or 64 bit. Please help.

Comment: Please tell me what you see on the third line when you open your terminal and run the following command: `java -version`. you should be seeing OpenJDK 32 or 64 -Bit

Comment: ```Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)```
This is written in 3 line.

Comment: You have 32 Bits Oracle

Comment: This is most likely the issue because clicking the big red button on https://java.com/en/download/ automatically downloads the 32-bit. That was my issue. The 64-bit installation lives here: https://java.com/en/download/manual.jsp.